# User Notifications Swift 3

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, firebase, notifications, swift3

I want to send simple User Notifications when a Button is pressed. I used a tutorial from the internet, bit it still doesn't work.
The error is "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT" in the AppDelegate

Here ist the Code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class Map: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Senden von Mitteilungen?
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func Notification(_ sender: Any) {

        //Set the content of the notification
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Achtung!"
        content.subtitle = "Verbindung zum Beacon wurde getrennt"
        content.body = "---"

        //Set the trigger of the notification -- here a timer.
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
            timeInterval: 10.0,
            repeats: false)

        //Set the request for the notification from the above
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: "10.second.message",
            content: content,
            trigger: trigger
        )

        //Add the notification to the currnet notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(
            request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the App Delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}

//EXTENSIONS

// Die Tastatur wird geschlossen, sobald der User außerhalb von ihr klickt
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I hope someone knows my mistake :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Of course: https://makeapppie.com/2016/08/08/how-to-make-local-notifications-in-ios-10/

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your `@IBAction` method to something else. You have a namespace conflict.
2. Ensure the `@IBAction` is actually linked to a button and fired (add a comment or breakpoint to the method).

---

**Edit:** Move your `FIRApp.configure()` out of applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. This has been known to cause crashes.

```
...

override init() {
    FIRApp.configure()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}

...
```

---

Tip: start method names with a lowercase letter. Classes with uppercase letters. This way you can easily identify these later.

Comment: You mean i should rename "Notification"? When I do this the error still is showing

Comment: I need a little more SIGABRT (Signal Abort) is thrown on fatal errors but it can literally be a thousand different thing. Can you update your question with all relevant code (including the AppDelegate)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133494/discussion-between-d00dle-and-luki512).